# Why a JQuery function fires only once on the same page

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple JQuery that takes the user hit "enter" key as clicking a particular button:

```
$('#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').keyup(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                $('#<%= btnSearchByRef.ClientID %>').click();
            }
        });
```

The button click will trigger a postback and display the search result in the same page.

This works great only in the first time. After the first time, this function is never triggered.

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: An input inside a form will trigger a submit on enter, you don't have to do it programatically ?

Comment: Check if `PostBack` property is set to true for the controls. Once there is a postback the event no longer work

Comment: It sounds like the binding is lost when you the refresh occurs.  Delegated event handlers might work.

Comment: In case my solution doesn't work, the best way to start debugging something like this might be to put a console.log statement at different points in your code, so you can see how much of it is executed when you click.  Which browser do you develop in?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using webforms, why not make use of the [DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx) property?

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="button1">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="button1" Text="Default" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

This property is used to specify which button gets clicked when the Panel control has focus and the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a delegated event handler would work?  Try this:

```
$('body').on("keyup",'#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>', function(){
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#<%= btnSearchByRef.ClientID %>').click();
        }
});
```

The explanation:
When you add an event handler, it will only bind to an element once.  If that element is refreshed, the binding is lost.

However, this is where delegated event handlers come in (really) handy.  Bind to an element that won't refresh (in this case, 'body').

In the code above, if I'm not mistaken, every time 'body' is clicked, it tests if '#<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>' exists.  Then if it does, it should execute your command.